# add data to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add data of a specific datatype to a new dataframe, however, the code returns an empty dataframe. I tried doing it with just one entry to see if that's the problem

```
date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
date.append(pd.Series(report2.loc[1,'Serv']), ignore_index=True)

print(date)
```

This returns an empty dataframe as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reassign `date`:

```
date = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
date = date.append(pd.Series(report2.loc[1,'Serv']), ignore_index=True)

print(date)
```

Indeed, according to the documentation, [append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) returns the appended DataFrame

> Returns: appended : DataFrame

Best